# Making and naming folders

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a script that is making a main folder with sub folders.
I am working on how to do it, this is how far i have managed to come.
I have just started to learn python.

My idea is: Making a folder named Somthing, with subfolders named somthingelse1,somthingelse2,somthingelse3.

Here is my code:

```
name_folder = input('Folder name:')
fil = int(input("How many folders:"))
start = 1

import os

def createFolder(directory):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
    except OSError:
        print ('Error: Creating directory. ' +  directory)

while start <= fil:
    print ("making folder")
    createFolder('./%s/'+ str(start)(name_folder))
    start = start + 1
```

And here is my output:

```
Folder name:test
How many folders:10
making folder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\folder.py", line 16, in <module>
    createFolder('./%s/'+ str(start)(name_folder))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Some help or poiners would help me thx.

Comment: What are you expecting `str(start)(name_folder)` to do?

Comment: What were you hoping `str(start)(name_folder)` would produce? `str(start)` is a string, and adding `(...)` to that tries to call that string as if it is a function.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to use `'./%s/%d' % (name_folder, start)` instead? That puts two values into a string, so `./test/1` and `./test/2`, etc.

Comment: However, you really want to use `os.path.join()` for combining path elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're wanting to do this

```
createFolder('./{}/somethingelse{}/'.format(namefolder, start))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to write so:

```
createFolder('./%s/'%name_folder + str(start)) # but this is not recommended
```

You should do:

```
 createFolder('./{}/{}'.format(name_folder, start))
```